Was Hanuman attacked by Indra when he tried to swallow the Sun?
I am watching a Ramayana serial in which there is an interlude when little Hanuman flies up in the sky and tries to swallow the Sun, thinking it is a fruit.  Indra gets upset by that and attacks Hanuman with his Vajra, killing him.  Hanuman's father Vayu then gets very angry and withdraws air from all living beings.  finally, Siva and Brahma intervene and revive Hanuman.  But since his jaw got broken by the vajra, he got the name "Hanuman" from this incident.
Is this in any canonical scripture?

Yes.

While still a child, you didst see the sun rise over the great forest
and taking it to be a fruit sought to seize it. Bounding into the air,
you didst mount up for a thousand yojanas, O Great Monkey and, though
the burning rays of the sun beat upon you, you didst not falter.
Seeing you rushing through space, Indra, full of wrath, hurled this
thunderbolt at you, whereupon, falling, you didst fracture your left
jaw on the point of a rock from which arises your name, Hanuman.


Sarga 66, Kishkindha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.


Hanuman's attempt to swallow the sun as a child is mentioned in ramayana. Ramayana divided into 7 kandas starts with bala kanda. There are references to hanumans attempt in both bala kanda and kishkinda kanda of ramayana.
This short story is also present in other scirptures like shiva puran, etc. but ramayan is the most well known one.
There are multiple stories about the attack. Some say that indra tried to negotiate as with Vayu and Vayu tried to convince hanuman before the attack. But hanuman as a child was stubborn and continued forcing indra as the lord of devas to retaliate intentionally causing hanuman to be knocked out instead of causing permanent injury.
Irrespective of all the different versions, it is a constant that they all include hanumans attempt to reach the sun. This includes ramayana.
